# Как запускать php скрипты на сайте, написанном на node.js?

Tags: php, linux, node.js, apache, веб-сайт

Стоит задача запускать php скрипты на сайте, который написан на платформе node.js. Обращение к php должно осуществляться через определенную ссылку сайта.
Какой порядок действий, чтобы совместить эти технологии на сервере c ОС Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### На примере

---

**1.** Создаём `index.js`:

```js
'use strict';

const {spawn} = require('child_process');

//...

const php = spawn('php', ['-v']);

php.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(`STDOUT\n\n${data}`));

//...

const phpFile = spawn('php', ['app.php']);

phpFile.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(`STDOUT\n\n${data}`));

//...

const phpFileExecutable = spawn('./app.php.executable');

phpFileExecutable.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(`STDOUT\n\n${data}`));
```

**2.** Создаём `app.php`:

```php
<?php

echo 'PHP file', "\n";
```

**3.** Создаём `app.php.executable` и делаем его исполняемым:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

echo 'Executable PHP file', "\n";
```

```sh
chmod +x app.php.executable
```

**4.** Запускаем:

```sh
node index.js
```

Пример вывода (`stdout`):

```
STDOUT

PHP 8.0.5 (cli) (built: May  3 2021 11:30:57) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.5, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.5, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans

STDOUT

PHP file

STDOUT

Executable PHP file
```

---

- https://replit.com/@w3lifer/Running-PHP-scripts-through-Nodejs#index.js
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35586247/4223982

Comment: Хотел уточнить, чтобы этот код работал, необходима установка сервера Apache и интерпретатора PHP?

Comment: @Jug-IT, сервен не нужен, достаточно просто PHP.